# create pdf from blob in popup window

Tags: php, pdf, popup, blob

I am trying to open a pdf blob in popup window.  I don't want to write the blob back to disk for security reasons.  I am using php to extract the blob and can produce a pdf document from php using the header() command to set 'content-type: application/pdf', write the blob to the current page.  That's fine, but I am afraid the user will close the window when done, rather than go back to the php page, thus exiting the app.  I can use php  to create a page, and pass the blob to javascript and let it create the popup, and write the contents, but then all I get is the raw contents of the pdf file, not rendered by the PDFreader.

php test code that creates the page with popup:

```
<?php
$pdf = $row['AttachmentDecBlob'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function loadpdf() {
    w = window.open("","viewer.pdf");
    w.document.write(hdr + "\r\n");
    w.document.write(pdf);
}
<?php
print "var hdr=\"Content-type: application/pdf\"\n";
print "var pdf=\"" . mysql_real_escape_string($pdf,$link) . "\"\n"; 
?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type=button value='Viewer' onClick="loadpdf();return true;"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a way to set the content-type of the new window to pdf, or possibly someone can suggest another method to view that pdf blob in a separate window.